# SQL Server, string to be substring in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

In SQL Server, my table structure is like this:

| OrderID | CustomerID | SerialNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58258 | 877 | OW13355-OW13356-OW13357-OW13358 |
| 58364 | 6 | OW13269-OW13270-OW13271-OW13272 |
| 58816 | 20315 | OW13940-OW13941-OW13942 |
| 59063 | 93085 | OW13676-OW13677-OW13678-OW13679 |
| 59114 | 16713 | OW12504-OW12505-OW12506 |
| 59519 | 470 | OW14361-OW14362-OW14363 |
| 59769 | 34820 | OW13928-OW13929-OW13930 |
| 60318 | 22424 | OW14081-OW14082-OW14083-OW14084-OW14085-OW14086 |
| 60318 | 22424 | OW14087-OW14088-OW14089 |
| 30858 | 16962 | EF 22567 9 |
| 8097 | 6 | OW76879 |

In the `serialNo` column, multiple serial no are entered in a row sometimes. I want to extract every serial number which are concatenated by - sign and make a new row. Every row should only have 1 serial number. For example, I want to  shows 4 records for `orderid = 58258` in a select.

Can this be done?

Result should be

| OrderID | CustomerID | SerialNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58258 | 877 | OW13355 |
| 58258 | 877 | OW13356 |
| 58258 | 877 | OW13357 |
| 58258 | 877 | OW13358 |

This given table structure should shows 35 records for 11 records. Can you please help me with the query?

I am using `CHARINDEX` for finding the `'-'` character, but how to find multiple occurrences of `'-'` and then select as a multiple rows?

Comment: Don't tag spam. Tag the RDBMS you are using and ***only*** that RDBMS.

Comment: For SQL server use STRING_SPLIT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, value  
FROM Table1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SerialNo, '-');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `string_split` function!

```
   select orderid, customerid, v.value SerialNo
    from Table t
    cross apply String_Split(t.SerialNo,'-') v
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response